# find equilibrium points in matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matlab

I need help with this material:

> The dynamics growth of two populations is expressed by the system of equations:
>   ($x=$ prey, $y=$predator, $0 \leq t \leq 30$)
>
> $$\dot x=x(1-x)-\frac{2xy}{y+x}\qquad\dot y=-1.5y+\frac{2xy}{y+x}$$
>
> Use Matlab to determine numerically the equilibrium points of the populations and their types (stable or unstable). Plot the graph of the dynamics of the two populations ($x$ and $y$ vs. $t$). Mark the equilibrium points on the graph.

I have no idea how to draw the graph and find the equilibrium points , please help me with this. thanks

Here are all the details[image]

where :  $a=2$, $b=2$, $m=1.5$, $0 \le t \le 30$

I got the following results when x=y=2 (Without critical points):

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: You haven't told us what z and w are.

Comment: Hi new user! $$\color{red}{\Large\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}$$ Don't worry about it now (since you're new) but you might like to know that we prefer to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: This will guide you through the process and you can figure out how to do this in Matlab.

- To find the critical points, you want to simultaneously solve $x' = 0, y' = 0$. You will get two critical points at $$(x,y) = \left(\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{6}\right), (1, 0)$$
- You can then determine the types of critical points these are by finding the Jacobian, $J(x, y)$, and evaluating the eigenvalues of the $2x2$ Jacobian. In the phase portrait below, you can see we have a stable and an unstable critical point.
- The Phase portrait will show these two critical points and should look something like:

[image]

- For Matlab, you can see some examples [*here*](http://jitkomut.lecturer.eng.chula.ac.th/matlab/dynamics.html) of how to draw that pahse protrait. Also, see [*MathWorks*](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/examples.html?file=%2Fproducts%2Fdemos%2Fshipping%2Fmatlab%2Flotkademo.html). Also see this [*book*](http://books.google.com/books?id=EIgTh2IBXCgC&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=matlab+predator+prey+phase+portrait&source=bl&ots=K-mwquMKey&sig=o4qdZ958LCklNm9fz7ZqnIy1HuQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Dm_QUr_LGM32oAT18YDICg&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=matlab%20predator%20prey%20phase%20portrait&f=false) by S. Lynch.

Comment: thanks a lot,

Which point is a stable ?

Comment: $(1/2, 1/6)$. You can actually see these points on the phase portrait. $(1,0)$ is an unstable saddle point. Please recall to upvote and/or accepts answers that are helpful.

Comment: I know it's not customary, but no idea how to write the code to this exercise
and I have to submit it in a few hours, please help me.

Exercise:

1. Use Matlab to determine numerically the equilibrium points of the populations and their types (stable or unstable). 
2. Plot the graph of the dynamics of the two populations (x and y, t).  Mark the equilibrium points on the graph. 
3. Plot the graph (phase plane plot) (x, y). Mark the equilibrium points on the graph. 


Thanks again

Comment: Ok, thank you.
If someone can help me with the code, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: There is a stack exchange for it, but they expect the same as this site - that you do some work first. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab

Comment: The problem is for a two-dimensional system. How can we find the stable points in case there is a three-dimensional system?? could you give me some light?? I need to submit a project and I'd be very glad if you could help me. I tried getting a result with the Variational Matrix, but it is too tiresome. I'd be glad if it could be done with less effort.

Comment: @AnishDarnal: The process is exactly the same and there are even tools to draw a 3D Phase Portrait. However, if you have a new question, please post it. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti To find the equilibrium points I tried the following code, `syms x(t) y(t)
eqns=[diff(x,t)==x*(1-x)-(2*x*y/(y+x));diff(y,t)==-1.5*y+(2*x*y/(y+x))];
[xSol(t),ySol(t)]=dsolve(eqns);`
But, I get an error as "Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. Error using sym/subsindex (line 1367)
Indexing input must be numeric, logical or ':'." How to find the equilibrium solution using Matlab? Is it by using a solver like ode45